# How to recover data from Dell dimension 9150 RAID 0 on another system?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, raid-0, dell-dimension

I have a Dell Dimension 9150 which has failed. I'm trying to recover the data. 
It had two SATA 250GB drives in RAID 0 configuration.

I'm trying to use a shuttle PC running Windows7 to recover the data from the drives which contained an XP boot volume. I just want the data, it doesn't have to boot.

What program would I need to rebuild / interrogate the drives (one of them is failing the onboard hardware test)? What drivers would I need to install?

Windows7 sees the drive as one partition but doesn't see volume information.
Ubuntu can see the drive as one partition and also can tell what the drive is called, but can't access the data

Any help appreciated!! :)

Comment: What kind of RAID was used? If it is a hardware RAID controller you will need to move it from the old computer and plug in in the new computer. If it is software raid you are lucky. If it is windows fake RAID (IRRT) then you just learned a hard lesson. :(

Answer (score 1):

If one drive has failed, for all practical purposes RAID 0 is not recoverable without special tools. If the data is worth more than about $5,000 or so, send it to a data recovery specialist. Otherwise, get our your backups.

Answer (score 1):

I have two drives configured as 1 RAID 0 and 1 RAID 1 drives. While I was able to install the drive(s) to recover data from the redundant partition, I had no luck on the disk side.

Unfortunately, the only sure way or even the cheapest way to recover is to install the two disks in anther 9150 or XPS400 to read them off. Try getting a refurbished unit online; it's much cheaper than sending the drive to recovery service.